# Update of the last element of a dataframe by another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nameCompany': ['Piestrita Inc', 'Total Play', 'Yate Inc', 'Spider Comp', 'Tech solutions', 'LG Inno'], 
                   'code': ['1', '1', '2', '3', '3', '3']
                    'results': ['Rick', 'Patram', 'Pulis', 'Marie', 'Landon', 'Freddy']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'nameCompany': ['Alaska Inc', 'Kira', 'Joli Molly', 'Health Society'], 
                   'code': ['1', '2', '3', '3']})
```

**df**:

| nameCompany | code | results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Piestrita Inc | 1 | Rick |
| Total Play | 1 | Patram |
| Yate Inc | 2 | Pulis |
| Spider Comp | 3 | Marie |
| Tech solutions | 3 | Landon |
| LG Inno | 3 | Freddy |

**df2**:

| nameCompany | code |
| --- | --- |
| Alaska Inc | 1 |
| Kira | 2 |
| Joli Molly | 3 |
| Health Society | 3 |

I need to make an update in the df in order to update the value of companyName if it appears in the df2 the code of the df, this update must be on the last element of the df if only one code appears in the df2 but if more appear it must be in the last positions, therefore, the output should be the following one:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'nameCompany': ['Piestrita Inc', 'Alaska Inc', 'Kira', 'Spider Comp', 'Joli Molly', 'Health Society'], 
                   'code': ['1', '1', '2', '3', '3', '3']
                    'results': ['Rick', 'Patram', 'Pulis', 'Marie', 'Landon', 'Freddy']})
```

**df_new**:

| nameCompany | code | results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pietrista Inc | 1 | Rick |
| Alaska Inc | 1 | Patram |
| Kira | 2 | Pulis |
| Spider Comp | 3 | Marie |
| Joli Molly | 3 | London |
| Health Society | 3 | Freddy |

I have tried with the update method but I have not obtained the expected results, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False` for counter column from last values, then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by it and `code` and last use [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('code').cumcount(ascending=False)
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('code').cumcount(ascending=False)


df = df.merge(df2, on=['code','g'], how='left', suffixes=['','_']).drop('g', axis=1)
df['nameCompany'] = df.pop('nameCompany_').combine_first(df['nameCompany'])
print (df)
      nameCompany code results
0   Piestrita Inc    1    Rick
1      Alaska Inc    1  Patram
2            Kira    2   Pulis
3     Spider Comp    3   Marie
4      Joli Molly    3  Landon
5  Health Society    3  Freddy
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed!